# Store paused/stopped chronometer time on button click , then compare the stored value with another value and show toast message

Tags: android, textview, message, toast, chronometer

I've checked a lot of similar topics and read a lot of examples, but could not find anything that would help me.
I'm making an app using Chronometer and displaying toast messages.
I want to store paused/stopped chronometer time on button click (button2), then compare the stored value with another value time (15 seconds, 30 seconds and etc.) and if it is bellow 15 sec show message "Good" , if it between 16 sec and 29 sec to show toast message "Super" and etc.
At the moment my code have start, pause/stop , reset buttons and it is showing toast message at 15 sec, 30 sec and etc.

This is the my MainActivity.java code:

```
package com.example.bobby.chronometer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static com.example.bobby.chronometer.R.id;
import static com.example.bobby.chronometer.R.layout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Chronometer chronometer;
private long pauseOffset;
private boolean running;
private View v;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layout.activity_main);
    chronometer = findViewById(id.chronometer);
    chronometer.setFormat("(%m,%s)");
    chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
            if (((SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase()) / 1000) * 1000 == 15000L) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Good!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (((SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase()) / 1000) * 1000 == 30000L) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Super!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (((SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase()) / 1000) * 1000 == 45000L) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Extra!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (((SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase()) / 1000) * 1000 == 60000L) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Great!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (((SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase()) / 1000) * 1000 == 90000L) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Amazing!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (((SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase()) / 1000) * 1000 == 120000L) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Awsome!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
public void startChronometer(View v) {
    if (!running) {
        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - pauseOffset);
        chronometer.start();
        running = true;
    }
}
public void pauseChronometer(View v) {
    if (running) {
        chronometer.stop();
          pauseOffset = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
          running = false;

    }
}
public void resetChronometer(View v) {
    chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    pauseOffset = 0;
}


}
```

This is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#B2EBF2"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context="com.example.bobby.chronometer.MainActivity"
android:keepScreenOn="true">/

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="142dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="62dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button1"
    android:onClick="startChronometer"
    android:text="@string/start"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="142dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="265dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button2"
    android:onClick="pauseChronometer"
    android:text="@string/stop"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="142dp"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="290dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button3"
    android:onClick="resetChronometer"
    android:text="@string/reset"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.387" />

<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/chronometer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#00E676"
    android:backgroundTint="#CCFF90"
    android:textSize="34sp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textAuthorSign"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="20sp"
    android:shadowColor="#030302"
    android:shadowDx="0"
    android:shadowDy="0"
    android:shadowRadius="3"
    android:text="@string/Press"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#7e1fdc"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic"
    android:typeface="normal"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.638" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-78dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="533dp" />
```

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: You didn't say what's the problem.

Comment: The problem is how to store the time value when chronometer is paused/stopped into textview and then to compare this textview with other pre-set time values.